# How can I open an activity on a double click? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

When *countDownTimer* is clicked twice, I want it to open the *FullScreen* Activity.

```
    countDownTimer.setOnClickListener(object : DoubleClickListener() {
        override fun onDoubleClick(v: View?) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Full Screen Mode!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val screenFull = Intent(this, FullScreen::class.java) //The Intent on this line is presenting an error
            startActivity(screenFull)
        }
    })

} //This bracket is from OnCreate

abstract class DoubleClickListener : View.OnClickListener {
    var lastClickTime: Long = 0
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        val clickTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        if (clickTime - lastClickTime < DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA) {
            onDoubleClick(v)
        }
        lastClickTime = clickTime
    }

    abstract fun onDoubleClick(v: View?)
    companion object {
        private const val DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA: Long = 300 //milliseconds
    }
}
```

The code above presents the following error when the code is compiled.

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public constructor Intent(p0: Context!, p1: Class<*>!) defined in android.content.Intent
public constructor Intent(p0: String!, p1: Uri!) defined in android.content.Intent

How could I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

val screenFull = Intent(this, FullScreen::class.java)

With:

val screenFull = Intent(**this@YourActivityName**, FullScreen::class.java)

This will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's saying that the arguments you're passing in, `this` and the `Class`, don't match any of the constructors. That's because `this` refers to your `DoubleClickListener` object, not the `Activity` (or whatever `Context` you want to pass in)

If you delete part of `this` and start retyping it, it should give you autocomplete options for the outer objects you can see from that scope. `this@MyActivity` or whatever is probably what you want.

Also, in case you didn't know, there's a `GestureDetector` class that you can set a double-tap listener on. Here's how you can add an empty implementation so you only need to override the callbacks you want to listen for: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector#detect-a-subset-of-supported-gestures